# Some data missing when being inserted into MySQL

Tags: android, mysql

Like many, I am new to Android and Java programming. I am working on a project for my employer to scan labels and compare the serials for a match and then upload to a database. I have a MySQL database set up at home and it is inserting data as expected but some of the 'contLabel' scans are missing in the table even though they are clearly in the EditText boxes. Please excuse my cobbled code, I am still learning quite a bit and I am doing this to test. Can someone please explain why some of the data would be missing even though there is data in the required fields please? Thank you all in advance.

This is my JSONParser:

```
public class JSONParser {
static InputStream is = null;
static JSONObject jObj = null;
static String json = "";

// constructor
public JSONParser() {

}

// function get json from url
// by making HTTP POST or GET mehtod
public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
        List<NameValuePair> params) {

    // Making HTTP request
    try {

        // check for request method
        if(method == "POST"){
            // request method is POST
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params, 
"utf-8"));

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();
```

And here is my Activity with Async:

```
 // Called when Compare button is clicked   
public void compareAndInsert(View view) {
    HashMap<String, String> queryValues = new HashMap<String, String>();
    queryValues.put("pickTicket", getPickTicket.getText().toString());
    queryValues.put("userId", getUserId.getText().toString());
    queryValues.put("contLabel", getContLabel.getText().toString());
    queryValues.put("qrLabel", getQrLabel.getText().toString());
    String cL = getContLabel.getText().toString();
    String qL = getQrLabel.getText().toString();
    String subClabel = cL.substring(3);
    String subQlabel = qL.substring(3);

        if (subClabel.equals(subQlabel) && trigger == true) {
            Toast toast = new Toast(this);
            ImageView view1 = new ImageView(this);
            view1.setImageResource(R.drawable.pass);
            toast.setView(view1);
            toast.show();
            //controller.insertUser(queryValues);
            new InsertToDb().execute();
            ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.etContLabel)).setText("");
            ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.etQrLabel)).setText("");
            getContLabel.requestFocus();
        } else {
            Toast toast = new Toast(this);
            ImageView view1 = new ImageView(this);
            view1.setImageResource(R.drawable.fail1);
            toast.setView(view1);
            toast.show();
        }       
}       
public void clickToChange(View view) {
    trigger = false;
    this.callHomeActivity(view);
}
public void callHomeActivity(View view) {
    Intent objIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
            MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(objIntent);
}

class InsertToDb extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(ScanTruck.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Updating Database...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        String pickTicket = getPickTicket.getText().toString();
        String userId = getUserId.getText().toString();
        String contLabel = getContLabel.getText().toString();
        String qrLabel = getQrLabel.getText().toString();

        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pickTicket", pickTicket));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("userId", userId));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("contLabel", contLabel));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("qrLabel", qrLabel));

        // getting JSON Object
        // Note that create product url accepts POST method
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_create_product,

        // check log cat for response
        //Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

        // check for success tag
        try {
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) {
                // successfully created product
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"DbUpdated!", 
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                // closing this screen
                finish();
            } else {
                // failed to create product
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch (NullPointerException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;            
    }
    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog once done
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }

}
```

My PHP is normal but will post it anyway:

```
<?php
/*
 * Following code will create a new verify row
 * All fields are read from HTTP Post Request
 */
// array for JSON response
$response = array();
print_r($_POST);
// check for required fields
if (isset($_POST["pickTicket"]) && isset($_POST["userId"])&&isset
($_POST["contLabel"])&& isset ($_POST["qrLabel"])) {

$pickTicket = $_POST['pickTicket'];
$userId = $_POST['userId'];
$contLabel = $_POST['contLabel'];
$qrLabel = $_POST['qrLabel'];

// include db connect class
require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';

// connecting to db
$db = new DB_CONNECT();

// mysql inserting a new row
$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO verifyqr(pickTicket,userId, contLabel, qrLabel)  
VALUES('$pickTicket', '$userId', '$contLabel', '$qrLabel')");

// check if row inserted or not
if ($result) {
    // successfully inserted into database
    $response["success"] = 1;
    $response["message"] = "Product successfully created.";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
} else {
    // failed to insert row
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Oops! An error occurred.";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
}
} else {
// required field is missing
$response["success"] = 0;
$response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";

// echoing JSON response
echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

I do not have enough rep to post an image but the contLabel field is missing some of the data even though the data was clearly in the EditText boxes. Any help will be greatly appreciated. And I have searched for this problem extensively but nothing quite like mine. Thank you!

Anarchy

Comment: If you want to, insert the image link where you'd like it and I'll edit it in for you. But think about whether a textual representation may be more fitting. Screen shots of text are usually frowned upon in these parts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Activity you have:

```
new InsertToDb().execute();
((EditText) findViewById(R.id.etContLabel)).setText("");
((EditText) findViewById(R.id.etQrLabel)).setText("");
```

So this calls the AsyncTask and then sets the EditTexts to an empty String.
Since AsyncTasks run in another thread your UI thread doesn't wait for the Task to complete before resetting the contents and I would guess that the EditTexts get cleared before the AsyncTask accesses the information you want.

You should either:

- Move the clearing to the onPostExecute() in your AsyncTask if you don't mind any delays caused by the Tasks's workload
- Or pass the values read through a constructor to your AsyncTask instead of reading them from your AsyncTask directly as the values may have already been changed.

If you need clarification on any of that ask and I can supply example code.

On a side note, you should probably have those EditTexts and other Views you want access to as class level variables. Assign them in your onCreate and then just refer to them by variable name afterwards instead of pulling them from your layout and casting them anew every time you need to use them.

Comment: That was definitely the problem. Thank you very much!